# CATextLayer memory residue after deallocation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory, calayer

I've just recently gotten into iPhone development and i'm still in the process of figuring stuff out. While testing various CALayer and CATextLayer behavior, i've stumbled upon something interesting.

I've created an iPhone test app which only has 2 UIButtons in a view. One of them calls 'allocateAutoReleasedLayers' function and the other 'deallocateAutoReleasedLayers' respectively. The following code snippets represent function bodies.

```
-(IBAction)allocateAutoReleasedLayers:(id)sender
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 500; ++i )
    {
        CALayer * layer = [ CALayer layer ];
        [ master addSublayer: layer ];
    }
}

-(IBAction)deallocateAutoReleasedLayers:(id)sender
{
    master.sublayers = nil;
}
```

Now, the purpose of the test was to see how iOS handles layer autoreleasing. When run with the 'Allocations' analyzer the app takes up 646.452 bytes of memory. After I hit the 'allocation' button, the memory usage goes up to the 719.228 bytes to host all of the 500 empty layers created, which is ok since when I hit the 'deallocate' button, the used memory falls back to 656.732 bytes (i guess that the mismatch in the memory used before allocation and after deallocation is a result of iOS' internal memory management).

The interesting part happens when i change the part of the 'allocation' procedure to create CATextLayers instead of the CALayers.

```
-(IBAction)allocateAutoReleasedLayers:(id)sender
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 500; ++i )
    {
        NSString * layerString = [ [NSString alloc ] initWithFormat: @"1231" ];
        CATextLayer * textLayer = [ CATextLayer layer ];
        [ textLayer setString: layerString ];
        [ textLayer setFrame: CGRectMake( 0, 0, 100, 200) ];
        [ textLayer setFont: @"Helvetica-Bold" ];
        [ textLayer setFontSize: 20 ];
        [ master addSublayer: textLayer ];
        [ layerString release ];
    }
}
```

The app starts with the usual 651.868 bytes usage before the allocation and rises up to the 2.13MB used (i guess CATextLayers are pretty heavy on memory usage), and upon deallocation the memory falls back to the 950.372 bytes.

Now, my question is the following: what happened to cause those 300kB difference before allocation and after deallocation when dealing with CATextLayers. I guess that my misunderstanding of the way iOS manages memory might be the cause but I've used the exact same way of creating CATextLayer as I've used in CALayer creation.

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run your code on simulator and I can't see this behavior. Here are steps I performed:

1) Run app under 'Allocations' instrument.
2) Wait until it fully starts.
3) mark heap -> Heap(0)
4) a) allocate CATextLayer instances with `allocateAutoReleasedLayers:`
   b) deallocate with `deallocateAutoReleasedLayers:`
   c) mark Heap -> Heap(1)

operation 4 gives us a test pattern (Allocate-Deallocate-Mark heap), so

5) ADM(2) -> Heap(2)
6) ADM(3) -> Heap(3)
7) ADM(4) -> Heap(4)
...

Difference between Heap(n) and Heap(n-1) is about 2K when ADM(n) is performed and drops to 0.5-1k when ADM(n+1) is performed (this is probably because framework recreates some stuff and releases old one, I can notice this for CGDataProvider for example). Anyway stuff in Heap(n+1)-Heap(n) contains something irrelevant like CSEvent, UITouchData etc. which is most probably allocated to handle button taps.

Are you performing your test on device or simulator? How many times you repeat this ADM loop? What is the content of difference between subsequent heaps? This is interesting because 300k seems too much to me.

Comment: I've been performing my tests on an actual device, iPhone 3G - iOS v4.1. The 'ADM' loop has been caller around 7-8 times, and to be honest, i wasn't aware of Allocations' neat ability to show the difference in memory usage, between heap shots, let alone, isolating the objects responsible for acquiring it. You've been of much help on that area alone :)
I've pinpointed the memory allocation to come from 'CGFontCopyTableForTag' and tried to correct the problem by allocating and deallocating the table using 'CGFontCreateWithFontName' and 'CGFontRelease', but the problem still persists.

Comment: Are you calling all this functions (CGFontCopyTableForTag etc.) elsewhere? I can't see them in above snippets.

Comment: No, the above code snippets are 99% of code in the test project. The other 1% is the header file containing declarations. I guess that the function in question is being called by '[ textLayer setFont: @"Helvetica-Bold" ];' to initialize the font. I'm at work at the moment so i cannot test the code as we're on Windows here, but I'll get to it as soon as i get home. Thanks for the time invested in debugging the problem btw :) I'll try not defining a specific font, and maybe the iOS will use the one it finds already located in memory, a system font or something.

Comment: I've tested it on IPhone 4 & iPad 4 (iOS 4.2.1). Same results as before (1-6KB of objects in diff which are mostly reused in next iterations). Now it is getting interesting. Try to use this project for tests, may be it is a configuration issue - git://github.com/hoha/test_catextlayer_leaks.git

Comment: I've tried out your project and i get the same result when i add     `[self.view.layer addSublayer: master];` to the end of the `-(void)viewDidLoad` procedure. The reason I've added the later is that in the contrary, CATextLayers do not show up on the screen naturally, 'cause the `master` layer hasn't been assigned to a layer in the view. Heap(1)-Heap(Baseline) contains 280KB memory increase, and all of the subsequent heapshots grow for an amount close to 10KB.This

Comment: could mean that the problem lies in the project configuration. My project settings are set to: 'XCode 3.1-compatible'. All of the other settings are related to gcc compile options and such.

Comment: I've updated test project in repo with `[self.view.layer addSublayer:master];` and made it ignore first tap so we can 'warm up' buttons and make baseline heapshot without actually allocating `CATextLayer`s. I can see a huge performance drop (layers are rendering on screen) and a bigger Heap(1)-Baseline ~ 35KB. Heap(n) is about 10KB, but after several ADM it decreases to 0-1KB. And sum of subsequent heapshot diffs doesn't exceed some (reasonably small in my case) limit. So my guess is that it's not a leak, it's just Quartz Core reuses some internal stuff. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, the only thing i think it's safe to conclude is that the first time a font is requested by `[textLayer setFont:@"Helvetica-Bold"]`, thus calling the `CGFontCopyTableForTag`, the font table is allocated and persists in memory during the entire execution of the program. To verify, i created only a single `CATextLayer` instead of the previous 500, and the result was exactly the same. First Heap(1)-Heap(Baseline) difference was about 280KB in size, a result of `CGFontCopyTableForTag` call. I guess if i want to use some less memory expensive method, I'll have to create my own :) Thank you for

Comment: the time spent playing with the code, and giving me some insight into the ways 'Allocations' instrument can be used properly. Best regards, Miran.